# PIL Image import error and how to display images in a Tkinter application

Tags: tkinter, import, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I have a problem with the Python Image and ImageTk from the **PIL** module since I continue to get a *No module named PIL* error in my PyCharm Run Configuration (Python 2.7).
I know that this issue has been mentioned in several other questions, however I was not able to solve it. So I hope to find a solution here.

I created a conda virtual environment in PyCharm and successfully installed pillow and pil there.
[See a Screenshot of my Project Interpreter Window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhZOq.jpg).

Also, when I type into the console `import PIL` or `import Image` there is no error occuring.
However, when I run a script that imports PIL, a *no module named PIL* error occurs (same for `import Image`). [Here is a Screenshot of the PyCharm Run Configuration of my Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTkMR.png).

What also drives me crazy is that when I run the Python Script outside from PyCharm using the usual Windows 10 console, no import error occurs but the image I'd like to display on my UI is not shown correctly. [Here is a Screenshot showing the result of the Tkinter application on the left, while the image that should be displayed is shown on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbefe.png). So I expect the image on the right to appear in the Tkinter window where currently the grey stripes are displayed.
Below, there is the code I used to create this application:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        mainframe = self
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        img = Image.open("N:/temp/test.png")
        imgTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        imgLabel = Label(mainframe, image=imgTk)
        imgLabel.image = imgTk
        imgLabel.pack(side="bottom", expand="no")
        imgLabel.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W, padx=(10, 10), pady=(6, 0))

def on_closing():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

So, if someone would have a suggestion how to eliminate the import error and how to display the image correctly in the Tkinter application I would be very grateful!

Comment: You don't have to layout the `Label` twice, user either `.pack(...` or `.grid(...`.

Comment: ***the image ... is not shown correctly.***: [Edit] your question and explain what do you expect to be **correct'**?

Comment: @stovfl Edit is made, but leaving out pack() or grid() does not bring a difference

Comment: Leaving out the call to `pack` will make no difference because only one manager at a time can control a widget. When you call  `pack` on a widget and immediately call `grid`, the effect of `pack` is completely ignored.

Comment: @CarinaB: Works for me if i change to: `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`. Run [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GlitteringOlivedrabBoastmachine#main.py), but didn't have: ***the grey stripes***

Comment: I fixed the import error by deleting the run configuration in PyCharm and by creating a new one.
Hoewever, the grey stripes remain although I see no difference in my Code compared to the Live-Demo. Only difference I see is that I'm using Python 2.7 instead of 3.6 in the demo @stovfl

Comment: ***the grey stripes remain***: Have you checked your image by viewing with a image tool?

Comment: Yes, I also tried a number of different images and formats (png, jpg, gif) and also exported the ImageTk.PhotoImage to a file. This looks fine, but whenever I want to display the image in my Tkinter UI the grey stripes appear.